# Google Maps scrolling slow and phone app show ANR when try to show 50 marker

Tags: android, google-maps, service, timer, google-maps-markers

Hi I am trying to show 100 markers on google maps but when we render markers on the map. Google map scrolling stop and App show ANR. 
Below is my code to show Marker on Map.
Also, API calls every 5-sec using service.

Please what we do wrong.

```
 if (getWorkerSummaryListResponse.getErrorCode() == 0) {
                workerListList = getWorkerSummaryListResponse.getWorkerListList();
                Log.d(TAG, "setData: " + workerListList.toString());


                for (user.WorkerSummary workerBasicInfo : workerListList) {
                    userPosition = workerBasicInfo.getUserPosition();
                    workerAlarmStatus.get(workerBasicInfo.getUserAlarmStatus());
                    if (workerBasicInfo.getWorkerActiveStatus() == 1) {
                        if (!userPosition.toString().equalsIgnoreCase("")) {
                            if (!mOnlineWorkerList.contains(workerBasicInfo)) {
                                mOnlineWorkerList.add(workerBasicInfo);
                            }
                            userPosition.getGpsData().getLat();
                            userPosition.getGpsData().getLng();
                            markerOptions = new MarkerOptions();
                            markerOptions.icon(icon);
                            markerOptions.position(new LatLng(userPosition.getGpsData().getLat(), userPosition.getGpsData().getLng()));
                            markerOptions.title(workerBasicInfo.getWorkerInfo().getEmail());
                            //  mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(new LatLng(userPosition.getGpsData().getLat(), userPosition.getGpsData().getLng())));
                            // mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(new LatLng(userPosition.getGpsData().getLat(), userPosition.getGpsData().getLng()), 12.0f));//where 14.0 is the zoom level
                            marker = mMap.addMarker(markerOptions);
                            marker.setTag(workerBasicInfo);
                        }

                    }
                }
```

Service code:---

public class MyService extends Service {

```
public static final int notify = 20000;  //interval between two services(Here Service run every 5 seconds)
int count = 0;  //number of times service is display
private Handler mHandler = new Handler();   //run on another Thread to avoid crash
private Timer mTimer = null;    //timer handling
AuthorizeApp mAuthorizeApp;


@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not yet implemented");
}

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    mAuthorizeApp = AppManager.shareInstance(this).getAuthorizeApp();
    if (mTimer != null) // Cancel if already existed
        mTimer.cancel();
    else
        mTimer = new Timer();   //recreate new
    mTimer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimeDisplay(), 0, notify);   //Schedule task
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    mTimer.cancel();    //For Cancel Timer
    Toast.makeText(this, "Service is Destroyed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}


//class TimeDisplay for handling task
class TimeDisplay extends TimerTask {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        // run on another thread
        mHandler.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                // display toast
                mAuthorizeApp.getRealTimeInstrumentInfo(new GetInstrumentListTask(getApplicationContext()));
            }
        });

    }

}
```